# How set data in table "quote_address"

Tags: magento2, database

How to set data in table 
`quote_address` after placing an order? ty for answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some events. For example: `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`, `sales_order_place_after`

See more here: `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement`